# Program crashes on StartScanningForDevicesAsync() PLUGIN.BLE

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a Xamarin app based on TX/RX serial com, particularly with Xamarin.iOS. I am trying to connect an Arduino to my iOS app, with Plugin.BLE NuGet package. At the time I try to start scanning for devices, the app crashes without debugging logs. This is the command that holds the Task for known device:

```
public async Task Button_ConnectBT()
        {
            connected = false;
            _handler = CrossBluetoothLE.Current;
            _adapter = CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
            
            devicelist = new ObservableCollection<IDevice>();
            bt_state = "Not Connected";
            
            if (!_adapter.IsScanning)
            {
                devicelist.Clear();

                _adapter.ScanTimeout = 10000;
                _adapter.ScanMode = ScanMode.LowPower;

                _adapter.DeviceDiscovered += (s, a) =>
                {
                    devicelist.Add(a.Device);
                };
                if(!_handler.Adapter.IsScanning)
                    await _adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync(); //Breaks here
                foreach (var device in devicelist)
                {
                    if (device.Id.ToString() == "96af0bb8-cafa-5b07-a0d2-79c01a414e7ee")
                    {
                            ...
                    }
                    bt_state = "Connected";
                }
        }
```

Does anybody know why StartScanningForDevicesASync() is not working? Are there any permissions required by the  ios app? If permissions are the impediment, how can I figure them out?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Raúl.

Comment: do you get an exception?  Have you checked the application output or iOS logs for messages?  Have you tried adding any exception handling to capture the error?

Comment: I really do not have any useful output, due to the fact that app breaks with Native Crash Reporting. I'll attach a snap of the Native Crash in the comments.

Comment: I have recently worked with that plugin and it works just fine. Did you read the documentation? https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le There are examples on how to use it. Your code looks too complicated.

Comment: I'll read it carefully, thanks

Comment: Regarding the permissions for iOS, yes, you need permissions. Please check the documentation. You don't need to set the scan mode and interval, just try with the default values.

Comment: which version of Plugin.Ble are you using? I have the same problem with Plugin.Ble 3.0.0-beta1 on Maui .net7 on windows